# Is there a query method or similar for pandas Series (pandas.Series.query())?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, method-chaining

The `pandas.DataFrame.query()` method is of great usage for (pre/post)-filtering data when loading or plotting. It comes particularly handy for method chaining.

I find myself often wanting to apply the same logic to a `pandas.Series`, e.g. after having done a  method such as `df.value_counts` which returns a `pandas.Series`.

## Example

Lets assume there is a huge table with the columns `Player, Game, Points` and I want to plot a histogram of the players with more than 14 times 3 points. I first have to sum the points of each player (`groupby -> agg`) which will return a Series of ~1000 players and their overall points. Applying the `.query` logic it would look something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Points': [random.choice([1,3]) for x in range(100)], 
    'Player': [random.choice(["A","B","C"]) for x in range(100)]})

(df
     .query("Points == 3")
     .Player.values_count()
     .query("> 14")
     .hist())
```

The only solutions I find force me to do an unnecessary assignment and break the method chaining:

```
(points_series = df
     .query("Points == 3")
     .groupby("Player").size()
points_series[points_series > 100].hist()
```

Method chaining as well as the query method help to keep the code legible meanwhile the subsetting-filtering can get messy quite quickly.

```
# just to make my point :)
series_bestplayers_under_100[series_prefiltered_under_100 > 0].shape
```

Please help me out of my dilemma! Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that SO is the best place for this question as it's a question for the developers of that library, it's better to post on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) IMO

Comment: Changed the question title to be more SO-Like

Comment: Here is an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22347) in the pandas github discussing this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can add `query("Points > 100")`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Points':[50,20,38,90,0, np.Inf],
                   'Player':['a','a','a','s','s','s']})

print (df)
  Player     Points
0      a  50.000000
1      a  20.000000
2      a  38.000000
3      s  90.000000
4      s   0.000000
5      s        inf

points_series = df.query("Points < inf").groupby("Player").agg({"Points": "sum"})['Points']
print (points_series)     
a = points_series[points_series > 100]
print (a)     
Player
a    108.0
Name: Points, dtype: float64


points_series = df.query("Points < inf")
                  .groupby("Player")
                  .agg({"Points": "sum"})
                  .query("Points > 100")

print (points_series)     
        Points
Player        
a        108.0
```

---

Another solution is [Selection By Callable](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-callable):

```
points_series = df.query("Points < inf")
                  .groupby("Player")
                  .agg({"Points": "sum"})['Points']
                  .loc[lambda x: x > 100]

print (points_series)     
Player
a    108.0
Name: Points, dtype: float64
```

---

Edited answer by edited question:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Points': [np.random.choice([1,3]) for x in range(100)], 
    'Player': [np.random.choice(["A","B","C"]) for x in range(100)]})

print (df.query("Points == 3").Player.value_counts().loc[lambda x: x > 15])
C    19
B    16
Name: Player, dtype: int64

print (df.query("Points == 3").groupby("Player").size().loc[lambda x: x > 15])
Player
B    16
C    19
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Oh wow, bad example from my part! The groupby actually returns a `DataFrame`. But e.g. a `pd.DataFrame.value_counts()` returns a series where your solution comes in handy! Selection By Callable, I was not aware of that - thank you

Comment: Ok, I add answer for yur new problem - callable are rare used, because it is new functionality.

Comment: Ok, I see that it was added only recently. Good addition!

Answer (score 11):

Instead of query you can use `pipe`:

```
s.pipe(lambda x: x[x>0]).pipe(lambda x: x[x<10])
```

Comment: This only gives you the boolean mask. It does not query/filter the series.

Comment: @MichelePiccolini, are you sure? It does filter the series for me.

Comment: Yes, it does filter, it doesn't return the Boolean mask. Be careful, the lambda expression is `x[x>0]`, not just `x>0`.

Comment: This .pipe() method is a big eye opener to me.

Answer (score 10):

Why not convert from Series to DataFrame, do the querying, and then convert back.

```
df["Points"] = df["Points"].to_frame().query('Points > 100')["Points"]
```

Here, `.to_frame()` converts to DataFrame, while the trailing `["Points"]` converts to Series.

The method `.query()` can then be used consistently whether or not the Pandas object has 1 or more columns.