# Better use of apply to compute new values using actual iterated row and rows of same entire column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, apply

Based on this example data :

```
data = """value          
"2020-03-02"    2
"2020-03-03"    4
"2020-03-01"    3
"2020-03-04"    0
"2020-03-08"    0
"2020-03-06"    0
"2020-03-07"    2"""
```

- I'm ordering `value` by date as datetime index
- from `value` column i compute a new `cum_value` cumulated value column;
- for each row value `vc{i from 0 to n}` of `value_cum`,
- i search into the `vc'{j from 0 to i}` cutted series of `cum_value` the row which verify and maximise the ratio `vc{i} / vc'{j} >= 2`

At the end, i get for each day, the delta between actual day and the day which maximize the predicate. For this data, i get :

```
            value  value_cum  computeValue  delta
2020-03-01      3          3           NaN    NaN
2020-03-02      2          5           NaN    NaN
2020-03-03      4          9           3.0    2.0
2020-03-04      0          9           3.0    2.0
2020-03-06      0          9           3.0    2.0
2020-03-07      2         11           2.2    5.0
2020-03-08      0         11           2.2    5.0
```

**Edit :** More context information here

Actually this is a code to find the first doubling day rate for Covid19 number of accumulated death. :

- `value` is my death by day,
- `value_cum` is the accumulated death by day.

For each day, i search into the existing series when the ratio of cumulated deaths is multiplied by 2. This is why i cut series, to compute my ratio i only need the n previous date/rows (past day) before the actual day i want to test.

I found this computation on [COVID 19 our world in data](https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus#global-comparison-where-are-confirmed-deaths-increasing-most-rapidly) charts, but i want to compute this indicators for one country and for each day and not only the last day as picture show :)

[image]

For example, for the date 2020-03-04, i only need to compute ratio between 2020-03-04 and 2020-03-01 / 02 / 03 to find the FIRST date where ratio >=2

In this example 2020-03-04 there is no more death than 2020-03-03, so we don't want to compute a new delta ( the number of days before death multiply >=2  is the same than 2020-03-03 !). I explain this in Edit1/2 archived at the end of this post.

We use a dictionary to store the first occurence of each cumulated value, so when i see that cum_value = value, i search in the dictionary to get the correct date (9 return 2020-03-03) for ratio computation.

Here my actual working code to do that :

```
    import pandas as pd
    import io
    from dfply import *

data = """value          
"2020-03-02"    2
"2020-03-03"    4
"2020-03-01"    3
"2020-03-04"    0
"2020-03-08"    0
"2020-03-06"    0
"2020-03-07"    2"""

   df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

def f(x, **kwargs):

    # get numerical index of row
    numericIndex = kwargs["df"].index.get_loc(x.name)
    dict_inverted = kwargs["dict"]

    # Skip the first line, returning Nan
    if numericIndex == 0:
        return np.NaN, np.NaN


    # If value_cum is the same than the previous row (nothing changed),
    # we need some tweaking (compute using the datebefore) to return same data
    ilocvalue = kwargs["df"].iloc[[numericIndex - 1]]["value_cum"][0]
    if x['value_cum'] == ilocvalue:
        name = dict_inverted[x['value_cum']]
    else:
        name = x.name

    # Series to compare with actual row
    series =  kwargs["value_cum"]
    # Cut this series by taking in account only the days before actual date
    cutedSeries = series[series.index < name]
    rowValueToCompare = float(x['value_cum'])

    # User query to filter rows
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171498/is-there-a-query-method-or-similar-for-pandas-series-pandas-series-query
    result = cutedSeries.to_frame().query(f'({rowValueToCompare} / value_cum) >= 2.0')

    # If empty return Nan
    if result.empty:
        return np.NaN, np.NaN 

    # Get the last result
    oneResult = result.tail(1).iloc[:, 0]
    # Compute values to return
    value = (rowValueToCompare/oneResult.values[0])
    idx = oneResult.index[0]
    # Delta between the actual row day, and the >=2 day
    delta = name - idx

    # return columns
    return value, delta.days

df_cases = df >> arrange(X.index, ascending=True) \
        >> mutate(value_cum=cumsum(X.value))


df_map_value = df_cases.drop_duplicates(["value_cum"])
dict_value = df_map_value["value_cum"].to_dict()
dict_value_inverted = {v: k for k, v in dict_value.items()}
print(dict_value_inverted)

df_cases[["computeValue", "delta"]] = df_cases.apply(f, result_type="expand", dict=dict_value_inverted, df=df_cases, value_cum= df_cases['value_cum'],axis=1)
print(df_cases)
```

I'm not really happy with this code, i found that passing the entire DF to my apply method was weird.

I'm sure there is some better code in Panda to do that in less lines, and more elegantly, using probably nested apply method, but i don't found how.

The dictionnary method to store date of the first duplicate is also weird, i don't know if it's possible to do that using apply (reusing result of previous computation during apply) or if the only way was to write a recursive function.

**QUESTION UPDATED WITH EDIT 1/2/3, WORKING WITH DUPLICATE VALUES**

**EDIT ARCHIVED**

**Edit 1 :**

```
data = """value          
"2020-03-02"    1
"2020-03-03"    0
"2020-03-01"    1
"2020-03-04"    0
"2020-03-05"    4"""
```

I see that my code doesn't take in account when there is value equal at zero.

```
                value  value_cum  computeValue  delta
2020-03-01      1          1           NaN    NaN
2020-03-02      1          2           2.0    1.0
2020-03-03      0          2           2.0    2.0
2020-03-04      0          2           2.0    3.0
2020-03-05      4          6           3.0    1.0
```

2020-03-03 computeValue is equal to 3.0 and not 2.0, dela is equal to 2.0 days and not 1.0 days (like 2020-03-02)

I cannot access previous values during apply computation, so i search another way to do that.

**Edit 2 :**

Found a way passing a pre-computed dictionnary :

- removing duplicate
- dictionnary where value_cum return a timestamp

```
   df_map_value = df_cases.drop_duplicates(["value_cum"])
   dict_value = df_map_value["value_cum"].to_dict()
   dict_value_inverted = {v: k for k, v in dict_value.items()}
   print(dict_value_inverted)
```

Now, when i found a cum_value equal to some value, i return the index used for computation.

Comment: Can you tell what is the problem after the edits?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean by "the `vc'{j from 0 to i}` cutted series of `cum_value` the row which verify and maximise the ratio `vc{i} / vc'{j} >= 2`". Can you explain what is going on here in a bit more words?

Comment: @jorijnsmit i update with more context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Some points***

The example you gave is a bit simple and I believe make it a bit harder to think in a more generic case. I then generated random data for 30 days using numpy.

By seeing the link you sent, I think they're showing us "how many days 
is the latest day that current day is double of apart from current_day".

To show this explicitly I will use very verbose column names in pandas and 
before calculating the metrics you want, I will build in the dataframe a reference list called `days_current_day_is_double_of` wich will for each row(day) calculate a list of days which the current deaths_cum is double of the day deaths_cum.

This column later can be substituted for a simple np.where() operation every time you want to find this for a row, if you don't want to keep a reference list in the dataframe. I think it's clearer keeping it.

***generating data***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

#n_of_days = 30
#random_data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=n_of_days)
#date_range = pd.date_range(start="2020-03-02",freq="D",periods=n_of_days)
#random_data = pd.DataFrame({"deaths":random_data})
#random_data.index = pd.to_datetime(date_range)
#df= random_data

import requests
import json
response = requests.get("https://api-covid.unthinkingdepths.fr/covid19/ecdc?type=cum")
data = json.loads(response.text)["data"]
deaths_cums = [x["deaths_cum"] for x in data]
dates = [x["dateRep"] for x in data]
df = pd.DataFrame({"deaths_cum":deaths_cums})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(dates)
```

***A verbose solution in pandas***

The key here is :

1. ***using apply(axis=1) to iterate over rows***,
2. ***using apply() to iterate over columns***
3. ***use np.where to do backwards search explicitly***
   I use np.where inside the helper function `check_condition(row)` to create the days references once and then use `find_index(list_of_days, idx)` to search again anytime
4. ***lambda functions but organize them with "helper functions"***

***big picture of the code***

```
    # create helper functions
    def check_condition(row):
+---  7 lines: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def delta_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row):
+--- 12 lines: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row):
+--- 11 lines: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def find_index(list_of_days,index):
+---  4 lines: {-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # use apply here with lambda functions
+--- 23 lines: df['deaths_cum'] = np.cumsum(df['deaths'])------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    print(df)
```

***Full solution code***

```
def check_condition(row):
    row_idx = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    currRow_deaths_cum = df.iloc[row_idx]['deaths_cum']
    rows_before_current_deaths_cum = df.iloc[:row_idx]['deaths_cum']
    currRow_is_more_thanDobuleOf = np.where((currRow_deaths_cum/rows_before_current_deaths_cum) >= 2)[0]
    return currRow_is_more_thanDobuleOf

def delta_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row):
    row_idx = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    currRow_deaths_cum = df.iloc[row_idx]['deaths_cum']
    list_of_days = df.iloc[row_idx]['days_current_day_is_double_of']
    last_day_currDay_is_double_of = find_index(list_of_days,-1)
    if last_day_currDay_is_double_of is np.nan:
        delta = np.nan
    else:
        last_day_currDay_is_double_of_deaths_cum = df.iloc[last_day_currDay_is_double_of]["deaths_cum"]
        delta = currRow_deaths_cum - last_day_currDay_is_double_of_deaths_cum
    return delta

def how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row):
    row_idx = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    list_of_days = df.iloc[row_idx]['days_current_day_is_double_of']
    last_day_currDay_is_double_of = find_index(list_of_days,-1)
    if last_day_currDay_is_double_of is np.nan:
        delta = np.nan
    else:
        delta = row_idx - last_day_currDay_is_double_of
    return delta

def find_index(list_of_days,index):
    if list_of_days.any(): return list_of_days[index]
    else: return np.nan

# use apply here with lambda functions
#df['deaths_cum'] = np.cumsum(df['deaths'])
df['deaths_cum_ratio_from_day0'] = df['deaths_cum'].apply(
                                lambda cum_deaths: cum_deaths/df['deaths_cum'].iloc[0]
                                                   if df['deaths_cum'].iloc[0] != 0
                                                   else np.nan
                                )
#df['increase_in_deaths_cum'] = df['deaths_cum'].diff().cumsum() <- this mmight be interesting for you to use for other analyses
df['days_current_day_is_double_of'] = df.apply(
                                        lambda row:check_condition(row),
                                        axis=1
                                            )
df['first_day_currDay_is_double_of'] = df['days_current_day_is_double_of'].apply(lambda list_of_days: find_index(list_of_days,0))
df['last_day_currDay_is_double_of'] = df['days_current_day_is_double_of'].apply(lambda list_of_days: find_index(list_of_days,-1))
df['delta_fromfirst_day'] = df['deaths_cum'] - df['deaths_cum'].iloc[0]
df['delta_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of'] = df.apply(
                                        lambda row: delta_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row),
                                        axis=1
                                            )
df['how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of'] = df.apply(
                                            lambda row: how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row),
                                            axis=1
                                                )
print(df[-30:])
```

PANDAS SOLUTION OUTPUT

```
            deaths_cum  deaths_cum_ratio_from_day0  \
2020-03-22         562                         NaN   
2020-03-23         674                         NaN   
2020-03-24         860                         NaN   
2020-03-25        1100                         NaN   
2020-03-26        1331                         NaN   
2020-03-27        1696                         NaN   
2020-03-28        1995                         NaN   
2020-03-29        2314                         NaN   
2020-03-30        2606                         NaN   
2020-03-31        3024                         NaN   
2020-04-01        3523                         NaN   
2020-04-02        4032                         NaN   
2020-04-03        4503                         NaN   
2020-04-04        6507                         NaN   
2020-04-05        7560                         NaN   
2020-04-06        8078                         NaN   
2020-04-07        8911                         NaN   
2020-04-08       10328                         NaN   
2020-04-09       10869                         NaN   
2020-04-10       12210                         NaN   
2020-04-11       13197                         NaN   
2020-04-12       13832                         NaN   
2020-04-13       14393                         NaN   
2020-04-14       14967                         NaN   
2020-04-15       15729                         NaN   
2020-04-16       17167                         NaN   
2020-04-17       17920                         NaN   
2020-04-18       18681                         NaN   
2020-04-19       19323                         NaN   
2020-04-20       19718                         NaN   

                                days_current_day_is_double_of  \
2020-03-22  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-03-23  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-03-24  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-03-25  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-03-26  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-03-27  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-03-28  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-03-29  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-03-30  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-03-31  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-01  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-02  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-03  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-04  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-05  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-06  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-07  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-08  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-09  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-10  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-11  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-12  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-13  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-14  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-15  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-16  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-17  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-18  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-19  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   
2020-04-20  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...   

            first_day_currDay_is_double_of  last_day_currDay_is_double_of  \
2020-03-22                             0.0                           79.0   
2020-03-23                             0.0                           79.0   
2020-03-24                             0.0                           80.0   
2020-03-25                             0.0                           81.0   
2020-03-26                             0.0                           82.0   
2020-03-27                             0.0                           83.0   
2020-03-28                             0.0                           84.0   
2020-03-29                             0.0                           85.0   
2020-03-30                             0.0                           85.0   
2020-03-31                             0.0                           86.0   
2020-04-01                             0.0                           87.0   
2020-04-02                             0.0                           88.0   
2020-04-03                             0.0                           88.0   
2020-04-04                             0.0                           91.0   
2020-04-05                             0.0                           92.0   
2020-04-06                             0.0                           93.0   
2020-04-07                             0.0                           93.0   
2020-04-08                             0.0                           94.0   
2020-04-09                             0.0                           94.0   
2020-04-10                             0.0                           94.0   
2020-04-11                             0.0                           95.0   
2020-04-12                             0.0                           95.0   
2020-04-13                             0.0                           95.0   
2020-04-14                             0.0                           95.0   
2020-04-15                             0.0                           96.0   
2020-04-16                             0.0                           97.0   
2020-04-17                             0.0                           98.0   
2020-04-18                             0.0                           98.0   
2020-04-19                             0.0                           98.0   
2020-04-20                             0.0                           98.0   

            delta_fromfirst_day  delta_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of  \
2020-03-22                  562                                    318.0   
2020-03-23                  674                                    430.0   
2020-03-24                  860                                    488.0   
2020-03-25                 1100                                    650.0   
2020-03-26                 1331                                    769.0   
2020-03-27                 1696                                   1022.0   
2020-03-28                 1995                                   1135.0   
2020-03-29                 2314                                   1214.0   
2020-03-30                 2606                                   1506.0   
2020-03-31                 3024                                   1693.0   
2020-04-01                 3523                                   1827.0   
2020-04-02                 4032                                   2037.0   
2020-04-03                 4503                                   2508.0   
2020-04-04                 6507                                   3483.0   
2020-04-05                 7560                                   4037.0   
2020-04-06                 8078                                   4046.0   
2020-04-07                 8911                                   4879.0   
2020-04-08                10328                                   5825.0   
2020-04-09                10869                                   6366.0   
2020-04-10                12210                                   7707.0   
2020-04-11                13197                                   6690.0   
2020-04-12                13832                                   7325.0   
2020-04-13                14393                                   7886.0   
2020-04-14                14967                                   8460.0   
2020-04-15                15729                                   8169.0   
2020-04-16                17167                                   9089.0   
2020-04-17                17920                                   9009.0   
2020-04-18                18681                                   9770.0   
2020-04-19                19323                                  10412.0   
2020-04-20                19718                                  10807.0   

            how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of  
2020-03-22                                              3.0  
2020-03-23                                              4.0  
2020-03-24                                              4.0  
2020-03-25                                              4.0  
2020-03-26                                              4.0  
2020-03-27                                              4.0  
2020-03-28                                              4.0  
2020-03-29                                              4.0  
2020-03-30                                              5.0  
2020-03-31                                              5.0  
2020-04-01                                              5.0  
2020-04-02                                              5.0  
2020-04-03                                              6.0  
2020-04-04                                              4.0  
2020-04-05                                              4.0  
2020-04-06                                              4.0  
2020-04-07                                              5.0  
2020-04-08                                              5.0  
2020-04-09                                              6.0  
2020-04-10                                              7.0  
2020-04-11                                              7.0  
2020-04-12                                              8.0  
2020-04-13                                              9.0  
2020-04-14                                             10.0  
2020-04-15                                             10.0  
2020-04-16                                             10.0  
2020-04-17                                             10.0  
2020-04-18                                             11.0  
2020-04-19                                             12.0  
2020-04-20                                             13.0
```

If you check `how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of` matches exactly with `XDelta` from the api :)

***There are so many small suggestions in case you want to really generalize your code. I don't think that's what you're looking for but I will list some:***

1. ***you can easily add a growth factor in the check_growth_condition function*** :

```
def check_growth_condition(row, growth_factor):
         ....
np.where((currRow_deaths_cum/rows_before_current_deaths_cum) >= growth_factor)[0] # <----- then just change 2 by the growth factor
         ....
```

2. ***you could reduce the reference list of `days current day is double of` to just the lastest date current day is double of, because all days before the lastest will also be double the ratio. I'll keep the first and last just for the sake of showing a "range of days".***

```
def check_growth_condition(row, growth_factor):
    ...
    # doing backwards search with np.where
    currRow_is_more_thanDoubleOf = np.where((currRow_deaths_cum/rows_before_current_deaths_cum) >= growth_factor)[0]
    if currRow_is_more_thanDobuleOf.any():
        return np.array([currRow_is_more_thanDobuleOf[0],currRow_is_more_thanDobuleOf[-1]]) # <------ return just first and last
    else:
        return currRow_is_more_thanDobuleOf # empty list
    ...
```

Note also if you want to get rid of the reference column, you just need to use `np.where((currRow_deaths_cum/rows_before_current_deaths_cum) >= growth_factor)[0]` wherever I am using the `check_growth_condition` function. again np.where is always doing the searching.

3. ***if you want to generalize deltas between current day to any other day for any columns, just pass day_idx and column name as parameter. you could even generalize `delta_from_any_day` instead of just subtract you pass a function as input such as `np.divide` to calculate ratios or `np.subtract` to calulate the deltas as I'm doing in the example***

```
def delta_from_any_day(row, day_idx, 
        column_name='deaths_cum',func=np.subtract):
    row_idx = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    currRow_deaths_cum = df.iloc[row_idx][column_name]
    if day_idx is np.nan:
        delta = np.nan
    else:
        day_idx_deaths_cum = df.iloc[day_idx][column_name]
        delta = func(currRow_deaths_cum, day_idx_deaths_cum)
    return delta
```

***Cleaner Pandas solution***

note that we're just reusing `check_growth_condition`,`find_index` to do backsearching and `delta_from_any_day` and to calculate the deltas. We're just reusing those three in all other helper function to calculate stuff.

```
def check_growth_condition(row, growth_factor):
    row_idx = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    currRow_deaths_cum = df.iloc[row_idx]['deaths_cum']
    rows_before_current_deaths_cum = df.iloc[:row_idx]['deaths_cum']
    currRow_is_more_thanDoubleOf = np.where((currRow_deaths_cum/rows_before_current_deaths_cum) >= growth_factor)[0]
    if currRow_is_more_thanDoubleOf.any():
        return np.array([currRow_is_more_thanDoubleOf[0], currRow_is_more_thanDoubleOf[-1]])
    else:
        return currRow_is_more_thanDoubleOf # empty list

def find_index(list_of_days,index):
    if list_of_days.any(): return list_of_days[index]
    else: return np.nan

def delta_from_any_day(row, day_idx, column_name='deaths_cum',func=np.subtract):
    row_idx = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    currRow_deaths_cum = df.iloc[row_idx][column_name]
    if day_idx is np.nan:
        delta = np.nan
    else:
        day_idx_deaths_cum = df.iloc[day_idx][column_name]
        delta = func(currRow_deaths_cum, day_idx_deaths_cum)
    return delta

def delta_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row):
    row_idx = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    currRow_deaths_cum = df.iloc[row_idx]['deaths_cum']
    list_of_days = df.iloc[row_idx]['rangeOf_days_current_day_is_double_of']
    last_day_currDay_is_double_of = find_index(list_of_days,-1)
    delta = delta_from_any_day(row, last_day_currDay_is_double_of, column_name="deaths_cum")
    return delta

def how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row):
    row_idx = df.index.get_loc(row.name)
    list_of_days = df.iloc[row_idx]['rangeOf_days_current_day_is_double_of']
    last_day_currDay_is_double_of = find_index(list_of_days,-1)
    delta = delta_from_any_day(row, last_day_currDay_is_double_of, column_name="day_index")
    return delta


# use apply here with lambda functions
#df['deaths_cum'] = np.cumsum(df['deaths'])
#df['deaths_cum_ratio_from_day0'] = df['deaths_cum'].apply(
#                               lambda cum_deaths: cum_deaths/df['deaths_cum'].iloc[0]
#                                                  if df['deaths_cum'].iloc[0] != 0
#                                                  else np.nan
#                               )
#df['increase_in_deaths_cum'] = df['deaths_cum'].diff().cumsum() <- this mmight be interesting for you to use for other analyses
df['rangeOf_days_current_day_is_double_of'] = df.apply(
                                        lambda row:check_growth_condition(row,2),
                                        axis=1
                                            )
df['first_day_currDay_is_double_of'] = df['rangeOf_days_current_day_is_double_of'].apply(lambda list_of_days: find_index(list_of_days,0))
df['last_day_currDay_is_double_of'] = df['rangeOf_days_current_day_is_double_of'].apply(lambda list_of_days: find_index(list_of_days,-1))
df['delta_fromfirst_day'] = df['deaths_cum'] - df['deaths_cum'].iloc[0]
df['delta_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of'] = df.apply(
                                        lambda row: delta_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row),
                                        axis=1
                                            )
df['how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of'] = df.apply(
                                            lambda row: how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of(row),
                                            axis=1
                                                )
print(df[-5:])
```

***Clean Output***

```
            day_index  deaths_cum rangeOf_days_current_day_is_double_of  \
2020-04-16        107       17167                               [0, 97]   
2020-04-17        108       17920                               [0, 98]   
2020-04-18        109       18681                               [0, 98]   
2020-04-19        110       19323                               [0, 98]   
2020-04-20        111       19718                               [0, 98]   

            first_day_currDay_is_double_of  last_day_currDay_is_double_of  \
2020-04-16                             0.0                           97.0   
2020-04-17                             0.0                           98.0   
2020-04-18                             0.0                           98.0   
2020-04-19                             0.0                           98.0   
2020-04-20                             0.0                           98.0   

            delta_fromfirst_day  delta_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of  \
2020-04-16                17167                                   9089.0   
2020-04-17                17920                                   9009.0   
2020-04-18                18681                                   9770.0   
2020-04-19                19323                                  10412.0   
2020-04-20                19718                                  10807.0   

            how_many_days_fromlast_day_currDay_is_double_of  
2020-04-16                                             10.0  
2020-04-17                                             10.0  
2020-04-18                                             11.0  
2020-04-19                                             12.0  
2020-04-20                                             13.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your long and detailled reply, i add some context for this problem because in this case context is important.

Comment: Sure, at first I thought you were concerned with improving speed  so my focus was in using a numpy approach to make it faster. Since I think you're not too concerned with speed I'll update with a pandas solution.

Comment: @reyman64 I updated my solution with a pandas solution, I think you misunderstood what the website graph is calculating, so I created some verboses  columns to show why I think so

Comment: I'm trying to understand the difference between our understandings of these chart.  If i understand well you think OWD chart provide a delta of days between : the last doubling day and the actual doubling day ? It's more complex to compute but also an  interesting indicator. So it's a delta between two doubling days occurence ? I don't see a way to go back on the OWD site to verify computation and check the behavior of their algorithm (On my computation, deltaX is my delta of days, see output here : https://api-covid.unthinkingdepths.fr/covid19/ecdc?type=cum )

Comment: I will update the solution with the actual data to confirm what I was saying :) The results I calculated matches with the api

Comment: @reyman64 I updated my solution, I had to remove the numpy part as it reached the limits of characters of stackoverflow (haha).

Comment: @reyman64 I updated the solution again, the first part I'm solving your problem itself and the second part  I'm addressing in more details ideas to use .apply in a better way if you have the patience to look at it. I recommend using the second part full code which is cleaner and more organized but both are working

Comment: Thanks so much for the time you take to develop your answer. Take me some time to review all your addition, but i validate your answer :) 
I precise that API url given before is the result of my computation / server using the code not optimized in the first post, and not the OWD API/Algorithm ;) So we don't really know how is computed the indicator on the OWD page :/

Comment: @reyman64, we can infer this from the graph you showed.... by the OWD indicator you mean "How long did it take to double?"

Comment: @reyman64 we can move the discussion to the chat if you want to discuss further

Comment: we could verify that by using the api for the countries that are there ?

Comment: Why not, we could discuss a little about that :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [pd.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

```
def track_growths(df, growth_factor=2):
    df = df.sort_index().reset_index()
    df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'])
    df['cum_value'] = df['value'].cumsum()

    merged = pd.merge_asof(df.assign(lookup=df['cum_value'] / growth_factor),
                           df.assign(lookup=df['cum_value'].astype(float)),
                           on='lookup',
                           suffixes=['', '_past'])

    result = merged[['index', 'value', 'cum_value']]
    growth = merged['cum_value'] / merged['cum_value_past']
    days_since = (merged['index'] - merged['index_past']).dt.days
    return result.assign(computeValue=growth, delta=days_since).set_index('index')
```

This has a configurable growth factor, in case you want to try something other than 2x.

```
track_growths(df)
#             value  cum_value  computeValue  delta
# index                                            
# 2020-03-01      3          3           NaN    NaN
# 2020-03-02      2          5           NaN    NaN
# 2020-03-03      4          9           3.0    2.0
# 2020-03-04      0          9           3.0    3.0
# 2020-03-06      0          9           3.0    5.0
# 2020-03-07      2         11           2.2    5.0
# 2020-03-08      0         11           2.2    6.0

track_growths(df, 3)
#             value  cum_value  computeValue  delta
# index                                            
# 2020-03-01      3          3           NaN    NaN
# 2020-03-02      2          5           NaN    NaN
# 2020-03-03      4          9      3.000000    2.0
# 2020-03-04      0          9      3.000000    3.0
# 2020-03-06      0          9      3.000000    5.0
# 2020-03-07      2         11      3.666667    6.0
# 2020-03-08      0         11      3.666667    7.0

track_growths(df, 1.5)
#             value  cum_value  computeValue  delta
# index                                            
# 2020-03-01      3          3           NaN    NaN
# 2020-03-02      2          5      1.666667    1.0
# 2020-03-03      4          9      1.800000    1.0
# 2020-03-04      0          9      1.800000    2.0
# 2020-03-06      0          9      1.800000    4.0
# 2020-03-07      2         11      2.200000    5.0
# 2020-03-08      0         11      2.200000    6.0
```

---

**Detailed explanation**

Starting from your original data:

```
df
#             value
# 2020-03-01      3
# 2020-03-02      2
# 2020-03-03      4
# 2020-03-04      0
# 2020-03-06      0
# 2020-03-07      2
# 2020-03-08      0
```

Let's first make sure that the index is sorted, then convert it back to a normal column and parse into a `datetime`. This is also a good time to add the cumulative value, which gets us through your existing prep:

```
df = df.sort_index().reset_index()
df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'])
df['cum_value'] = df['value'].cumsum()
df
#        index  value  cum_value
# 0 2020-03-01      3          3
# 1 2020-03-02      2          5
# 2 2020-03-03      4          9
# 3 2020-03-04      0          9
# 4 2020-03-06      0          9
# 5 2020-03-07      2         11
# 6 2020-03-08      0         11
```

Now here comes the big trick, in which `merge_asof` allows you to look up the half-rate rows directly:

```
merged = pd.merge_asof(df.assign(lookup=df['cum_value'] / 2),
                       df.assign(lookup=df['cum_value'].astype(float)),
                       on='lookup',
                       suffixes=['', '_past'])
merged
#        index  value  cum_value  lookup index_past  value_past  cum_value_past
# 0 2020-03-01      3          3     1.5        NaT         NaN             NaN
# 1 2020-03-02      2          5     2.5        NaT         NaN             NaN
# 2 2020-03-03      4          9     4.5 2020-03-01         3.0             3.0
# 3 2020-03-04      0          9     4.5 2020-03-01         3.0             3.0
# 4 2020-03-06      0          9     4.5 2020-03-01         3.0             3.0
# 5 2020-03-07      2         11     5.5 2020-03-02         2.0             5.0
# 6 2020-03-08      0         11     5.5 2020-03-02         2.0             5.0
```

This will perform a "backward" search to try and find a match for every row in the first DataFrame. Per the docs:

> A “backward” search selects the last row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is less than or equal to the left’s key.

Here the key is the `lookup` value, which is half of `cum_value` for the left (current) DataFrame, and equal to the `cum_value` for the right (historical) DataFrame. If we update the docs to match this case, it would read something like this:

> Select the last row in the historical DataFrame where `cum_value` is less than or equal to half the current `cum_value`.

This is exactly what you want: the most recent day in history with no more than half the case counts.

From here it is quick work to compute the derived `delta` and `computeValue` information and format the result.

```
result = merged[['index', 'value', 'cum_value']]
growth = merged['cum_value'] / merged['cum_value_past']
days_since = (merged['index'] - merged['index_past']).dt.days
result.assign(computeValue=growth, delta=days_since).set_index('index')
#             value  cum_value  computeValue  delta
# index                                            
# 2020-03-01      3          3           NaN    NaN
# 2020-03-02      2          5           NaN    NaN
# 2020-03-03      4          9           3.0    2.0
# 2020-03-04      0          9           3.0    3.0
# 2020-03-06      0          9           3.0    5.0
# 2020-03-07      2         11           2.2    5.0
# 2020-03-08      0         11           2.2    6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the data:

```py
import io

data = """value          
"2020-03-02"    2
"2020-03-03"    4
"2020-03-01"    3
"2020-03-04"    0
"2020-03-08"    0
"2020-03-06"    0
"2020-03-07"    2"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.sort_index()
```

First add the cumulative total of `df['value']` as a column:

```py
df['value_cum'] = df['value'].cumsum()
```

If I understand you correctly, you are looking at the growth factor of this cumulative total since its inception (i.e. its first entry; `.iloc[0]`):

```py
day_0 = df['value_cum'].iloc[0]
df['growth_factor_since_day_0'] = df['value_cum'] / day_0
```

Now all we need to do is to check how many days it took for it to reach `>=2`:

```py
((df['growth_factor_since_day_0'] >= 2) == False).sum()
```

You could specify a threshold like in the example you linked to prevent from getting an early hit (going from value `1` to `2` for example):

```py
day_0 = df['value_cum'].loc[df['value_cum'] >= 5].min()
```

This will return `NaN` in the `df['growth_factor_since_day_0']` column in case that threshold has not been reached yet, making sure we don't get false positives.